# "Error: expected a '{' introducing a lambda body" when trying to get char from map<char,char> C++

Tags: c++, encryption, lambda, compiler-errors, stdmap

```
char Substitution::encodeChar(char a, std::map<char, char>&){
    return &[a];
}
```

This is my implementation attempt (based on a pre defined Class header which I may not change for the assignment). In Visual Studio I get the error (see title) over the semicolon?

Trying

```
&.find(a)
```

instead gives me "expected an expression" over the period.

I think I spotted somewhere saying something about **const char** vs. **char** for this problem, but I can't wrap my head around it. I've used **map char char** earlier this way, but somehow using it in this context doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to treat `&` as a variable name. It's not. Variable names consist only of letters, digits, and underscores.

Actually, in the function parameters, `std::map<char, char>&` means that the type of the parameter is a "reference to `std::map<char, char>`". Note that I said "reference to". That's what the `&` means. It's part of the type and makes the parameter a reference parameter.

So you need to give your parameter a name and then use that name:

```
char Substitution::encodeChar(char a, std::map<char, char>& my_map){
    return my_map[a];
}
```

We can read the parameter `std::map<char, char>& my_map` as saying the `my_map` is a "reference to `std::map<char, char>`". Then, `my_map[a]` accessing the key `a` in that map.

Comment: I had my suspicions about the & and tried changing it for a word, which didn't work. However adding a name after the reference symbol solves it. I might have interpreted the assignment wrong and thought the lack of a name in the header meant I wasn't supposed to use one. I see now that names are not needed in class headers, only in implementations.